# Is there a way to get a range of indexes from a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to get a range of 5 sequential indexes from an array of indeterminate length.

My array might look like this: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

I know I can use array.slice() if I need to return something like [2,3,4,5,6], but sometimes I might need to return something like [6,7,0,1,2]

Is there a clean or built-in way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing built in that automatically wraps around, you need to write that yourself.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood right, you need something like this:

```
function array_indexes(arr, keys){
    let res = [];
    for(let k of keys){
        res.push(arr[k]);
    }
    return res;
}
```